# battleship game in python needs database or not

Tags: python, pygame

I'm going to design simple battleship game with Python and Pygame.
but I don't know whether I need database for this purpose or not , or generally which games need databases to be designed. 
I'll be thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: There is no general guidance when to use db. It's up to your individual requirements.

Comment: Please get to know the very basics of software development before you start writing any code. You are unable to design anything with your current knowledge.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko you're mean

Comment: I didn't intend to be mean, I'm sorry. I'm just stating a fact. It is clear from your question, that you have no idea about what a database is and how/when to use it. How can you design anything based on a db if you don't know what that tool brings? Do not get upset about it, just go and read some tutorials/books and understand the basic principles and ideas of software development. I'm sure you will succeed, you just need to put some effort into it. In the meantime, SO is not the place you should post these kind of questions to. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a db to have a simple game if you're just storing everything when the program is run. If you want to save the progress after starting and stopping your game then perhaps a database would be required